# Adding Styles like LineColor, Fill Color to SimpleFeaturePolygons while exporting them into a kml file

Tags: kml, style, geotools

I am trying to export features(polygons) in to a KML file. I am able to get KML file with the given features. Here all lines are coming in a white color. How can i give different colors to different polygons. Please suggest me.

Here my code

```
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    builder.setName(plotName);
    builder.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
    builder.add(sPolygon, Polygon.class);
    builder.length(32).add("AreaLocation", String.class);
    final SimpleFeatureType featureType = builder.buildFeatureType();
```

getting Feature Collection from featureList

```
    SimpleFeatureCollection collection = new ListFeatureCollection(builder.getFeatureType(), featureList); //featureList list of all polygons
```

exporting as a kml

```
            OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("my.kml");
            Encoder encoder = new Encoder(new KMLConfiguration());
            encoder.setIndenting(true);
            encoder.encode(collection, KML.kml, stream);
```

Comment: What should control the colour of the polygons?

Comment: When I am opening the KML file it is appearing that whole polygons are in white background here the link to image  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Vh2tWJlQW_QzAzQ0pXRHpHTmM/view?usp=sharing in this image there are 7 polygons but not showing since all are in while Color.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is no code to do this on [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) as GeoTools confines itself to reading and writing data formats and handles styling as a separate matter.

You could look at (and probably use) the code in [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) that handles [writing out KML with a style](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/master/src/kml).

Comment: But what might be the reason in my code at least the boundary lines of the polygons should be visible but  not appearing in the resultant KML.